# CSS Text underline animation issue

Tags: html, css, animation, underline

I'm trying to learn how to add an underline animation effect on my webpage, but am having a small issue.

Here's the code I used for the underline effect:

```
.cmn-t-underline {
position: relative;
}

.cmn-t-underline:after {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: -10px;
width: 0;
height: 3px;
background-color: dimgrey;
content: "";
transition: width 0.3s;

}
.cmn-t-underline:hover {
color: #333;
}

.cmn-t-underline:hover:after {
width: 100%;
}
```

And here's the code on my css:

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h1 class="text-center text-padding cmn-t-underline">Access Everywhere</h1>
        <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
```

And this is how it comes out once the animation is done:

[image]

My question is, how do I make it so that the underline only stays directly under the H1 header? I want the underline to start at 'A' and end at 'e', but I am having a hard time figuring out what to put in the code to fix this. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this small issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `display-table` on your `h1` to simulate block like behaviour without the 100% width...

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.cmn-t-underline {
    position: relative;
}
.cmn-t-underline:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    content:"";
    transition: width 0.3s;
}
.cmn-t-underline:hover {
    color: #333;
}
.cmn-t-underline:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
     <h1 class="text-center text-padding cmn-t-underline">Access Everywhere</h1>
     <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the display of the `h1` to `inline-block`

```css
.cmn-t-underline {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.cmn-t-underline:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    content:"";
    transition: width 0.3s;
}
.cmn-t-underline:hover {
    color: #333;
}
.cmn-t-underline:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <h1 class="text-center text-padding cmn-t-underline">Access Everywhere</h1>
   <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, that didn't seem to work unfortunately. The line is still longer than the H1 text.

Comment: really? do you have a screenshot? what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Firefox. And when I added inline-block it seemed to do the same thing, I don't know why. User 'Sexy Turnip's suggestion seemed to work however.